# FormData is posting only one image file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, form-data

I want to post multiple image files to the server. I have used formData (formDta.append()) which is getting only one image. it's not taking the multiple images

```
 **#contained-button-file** is the input file ID

uploadCategoryImages = () => {
    let formData = new FormData()
    let imagefile = document.querySelector('#contained-button-file')
    formData.append('image', imagefile.files[0])
    api.post('/api/v1/addimage/category/3', formData)
       .then(function (response) {
           console.log(response)
       })
       .catch(function (error) {
           alert(error)
       })   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current implementation only attempts to append the first element (`0`) of `imagefile.files`.

[Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) can be leveraged to append each element.

[FormData.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) also expects a name as it's first parameter, followed by a value, and lastly an optional filename.

See below for a practical example.

```
[...imagefile.files].forEach(file => formData.append('image[]', file))
```

Overall, your `uploadCategoryImages` function could be reduced to the following:

```
uploadCategoryImages = () => {
  const data = new FormData()
  const images = document.getElementById('contained-button-file').files
  [...images].forEach(image => data.append('image[]', image))
  api.post('/api/v1/addimage/category/3', data)
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(alert)
}
```

Comment: I am getting "imagefile.files.forEach is not a function" this error

Comment: My bad. `files` is a [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) (not an array), and therefore needs to be cast (using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) or [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) @RamyaMiiM

Comment: ^ (in order to use [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) - Otherwise a [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) or [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) statement would suffice.

Comment: Couldnt able to append multiple images in formdata

Comment: I've revised the name parameter in my answer to be `'image[]'`. The third snippet from [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#Example) suggests it should work @RamyaMiiM

Answer (score 0):

Yes `FormData` field can be assigned one file at time but you can append multiple file in `FormData` as below

```
uploadCategoryImages = () => {
 let formData = new FormData();
 let imagefile = document.querySelector('#contained-button-file');

 //loop through file elements and append file in formdata
 for(var i = 0; i <imagefile.files.length; i++){
    //you can name it anything here it will be image-0, image-1 like so
    formData.append('image-'+ i, imagefile.files[i]);
 }

 api.post('/api/azz/a/ss/ss/ss/s/', formData)
 .then(function (response) 
  {
  console.log(response)
  alert("Images have been uploaded Succesfully!!!");
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
  alert(error)
  })

}
```